# USB device not found in intellij on Windows 8

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea, adb

I'm trying to debug on an HTC One. The emulator works fine in intellij, but I'm unable to debug on the device.

I've tried the recommended solution here (http://vuknikolic.me/2013/03/10/idea-intellij-usb-device-not-found-android-problem/) but that still doesn't show my device.

The device is recognized by Windows when I initially plugged it in, but I do not see it in the devices list or in device manager.

I tried manually installing the google driver for an unknown device listed in device manager via these steps (http://donandroid.com/how-to-install-adb-interface-drivers-windows-7-xp-vista-623), but that did not work.

Any ideas?

**update**

Installing HTC Sync Manager. Will try that next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the [HTC Sync Manager](http://www.htc.com/uk/software/htc-sync-manager/) seemed to do the trick.